# Use String's replaceAll method to remove all tokens unless they follow a specific phrase

Tags: java, regex

I have a need to replace a particular token (in this case, `?`) with another token (we can start with `!` or something). String's `replaceAll` method will work for this. But, I don't want to replace the question mark if it happens to follow the token `action`. (That would be bad!)

I've tried `text = text.replaceAll("[^a][^c][^t][^i][^o][^n]\\?","!");` but that didn't work.

For example, I want `"test.action?param=lol?omg";` to turn into `test.action?param=lol!omg`. I know I could do something silly like

```
text.replaceAll("action\\?","%%%CRAZYTOKEN%%%")
    .replaceAll("\\?","!")
    .replaceAll("%%%CRAZYTOKEN%%%","action?");
```

but that just seems like a waste of time, especially on large strings. I'd rather do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a negative look behind

```
text.replaceAll("(?<!action)\\?", "!");
```

This asserts that the `?` does **not** follow `action`

Comment: So that basically goes "la de da de daa, where's the question mark. Hey there's one! Wait a minute... you're not okay because of my awesome negative look behind ray of death; I'll keep going on my merry way."? Is the question mark at the beginning of the parenthetical part of the negative look behind's syntax? Or is it because only I'm looking for a question mark?

Comment: I should rephrase that. It did exactly what I asked it to do - remove question marks. Turns out those question marks were not what was causing my XML to not load into my dhtmlxgridobject. It was the extra lines at the top of my jsp output. Why is `<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>` not default, seriously? *continues ranting for a considerable amount of time...

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [zero-width negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to only match `?`s which *don't* follow `action`:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?<!action)\\?", "!");
```

Note the extra `\\` before the `?`. You need to escape the `?` since it is a special character in regex.

Comment: 16 seconds, that's killer! :-(

Comment: Not at all, I've submitted near-identical answers within the same second as another answerer `:)`